# Python - Shortcircuiting strange behaviour

Tags: python, short-circuiting

In the following code fragment function `f` gets executed as expected:

```
def f():
  print('hi')
f() and False
#Output: 'hi'
```

But in the following similar code fragment `a` doesn't increment:

```
a=0
a+=1 and False
a
#Output: 0
```

But if we shortcircuit with  True instead of False `a` gets incremented:

```
a=0
a+=1 and True
a
#Output: 1
```

How does shortcircuit work for this to run this way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because `f() and False` is an expression (technically a single-expression statement) whereas `a += 1 and False` is an assignment statement. It actually resolves to `a += (1 and False)`, and since `1 and False` equals `False` and `False` is actually the integer 0, what happens is `a += 0`, a no-op.

`(1 and True)`, however, evaluates to `True` (which is the integer 1), so `a += 1 and True` means `a += 1`.

(also note that Python's `and` and `or` always return the first of their operands that can unambiguously determine the result of the operatio)

Comment: It might be worth clarifying "`(1 and True)` evaluates to `True` which is the integer 1."

Comment: Shouldn't  `a += 1 and False` resolve to `a = (a + 1) and False` as `+` operator has [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) then the whole expression resolve to `a = False`?

Comment: No, because `+=` is not an operator, it's an assignment instruction (statement, not expression). Assuming `__iadd__` is not overridden, `a += b` first evaluates `a`, then evaluates `b`, then adds the two together and reassigns the result to `a`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that

```
a+=1 and False
```

is equivalent to

```
a+=(1 and False)
```

and

```
a+=1 and True
```

is equivalent to

```
a+=(1 and True)
```

For example:

```
In [15]: a = 0

In [16]: a+=2 and True

In [17]: a
Out[17]: 1
```

Comment: Yep, that's it. In python assignment does not return value as in C.